# Manage build target variables in iphone project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos

We're transitioning to an automated build process for our iphone projects.  These projects can be checked out by individual devs, in which case all the API URLs need to point to a certain path.  There are also a variety of build environments, each with their own API root paths.

I could probably add multiple, different build targets, and have each of them include a different URLs definition file, but this seems like a lot of upkeep and a bit overkill.

Any best practices out there for swapping a few environmental variables for different build environments without much fuss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode [Configuration Files](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/400-Build_Configurations/build_configs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002692-SW8) are probably what you are looking for.  They put build settings in a text file for easier management.

Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcconfig

Comment: Close.  That's useful for setting actual build settings, but I'm looking for methods that can inject different URLs into my project.  From what I can tell, config files aren't really intended for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

In `Project` tree > `Targets` > high light a target > `Cmd-I` > in `Build` tab ...

scroll to `"GCC 4.2 - Precessing"` > `Preprocessor macros`

just add as much as needed, e.g.

```
  TARGET=8
```